# Executing multiple file transfer using threads and udp via batch file

Tags: python

I have created one batch file which looks like this :

```
python file1.py transfer_file_name
python file2.py transfer_file_name
python file3.py transfer_file_name
```

but after completing of first file transfer, it is getting stuck. It is not executing second line. I have used threads and udp protocol to transfer file.

Comment: share your code its difficult to understand the problem like this

Comment: sorry but i cant share it because its confidential @Inder

Comment: i am transferring multiple files to hardware from pc through ethernet and using udp protocol. i am transferiring as well as receiving response also but after one file transfer from batch file, unable to send another file.

Comment: Okay in that case it will be difficult but let's try: check if all threads are initialized properly, try without the first file, I. E. Start transfer from second one only. See if the result Is same, if yes then check if memory allocation to the script when it's running is invreasing if it remains the same it's probably waiting for some line to be executed since no code is available only you can figure out which line is creating issues